# How to login into tenant user from backend code using ABP Framework

Tags: c#, abp, abp-framework

I have been working on ABP Framework and got a task where I should log into Tenant User using credntials from backend application.
We are using eShopOnAbp template (ABP Version 5.1.4) and trying to login by following article
https://support.abp.io/QA/Questions/53/Login-From-Desktop-Client

However we are only able to reach till host admin user, not the tenant user as how to resolve tenant and reach tenant context is not workin,
Tried to user ChangeTenant methos also but still no luck.

It will be helpfull if we get the solution

Answer (score 0):

[eShopOnAbp](https://github.com/abpframework/eShopOnAbp) is not a template, it is a demonstration sample actually. It **doesn't implement multi-tenancy**. You can't use multi-tenancy features on that sample, you will need to manually add multi-tenancy like creating a new microservice to handle tenant management etc.